# Inline admin ignores max_num and extra if an instance exists

Tags: python, django

I've extended the standard Django User model with a UserProfile, and created a OneToOne relationship from the UserProfile to the User, like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(adminmodels.User)
    about = models.TextField('About the author', blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField('Picture (70px x 70px)', blank=True, upload_to='uploads/profile_pics', default='noone.png')
    user_site = models.URLField(blank=True, verify_exists=False)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Profiel"
    verbose_name_plural = "Profielen"
```

To get the corresponding admin form included in the User admin, I created an inline admin form, and added it to the user admin, like so:

```
# Inline admin for the user profile
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1
    extra = 0

# Include the extra form
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [UserProfileInline, ]

# Re-register the user form
admin.site.unregister(admin.models.User)
admin.site.register(admin.models.User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Than, lastly, to save an instance of UserProfile, I have a function connected to postsave. It looks like this:

```
def on_user_was_saved(sender,instance,created,using,*args,**kwargs):
    if type(instance) == adminmodels.User:    
        if created:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)
            profile.save()
        else:
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)
            profile[0].save()
```

Now, two things go wrong:

1. When saving the user with anything in the user profile field, the user is saved, and so is the instance of UserProfile, but the instance has been saved as if all fields were empty. When entering something new in these fields you can save that though, nothing goes wrong than.
2. A second instance of the UserProfile form becomes available; max_num is ignored.

## After benjaoming's input I've changed my post_save callback to:

```
    try:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = instance)
        profile.save()
    except:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = instance)
        profile[0].save()
```

However this doesn't solve either of the problems I already had.

Comment: Your last else block is wrong. You cannot subscript profile, since it is a single UserProfile object, ie. something that can be iterated like a queryset.

Comment: @benjaoming I don't quite get that. Fidling with that a little I find that it doesn't work like I expected indeed, but I can't figure out what it does do and you're answer is to cryptic for me to understand. Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: `get_or_create` returns a tuple, first one is the object and second a boolean telling if new object was created or not. Thats why the subscript is required, in the previous `if` call too infact.

Comment: Thanks, you're obviously right, I've altered it, see my edited post. This doesn't solve the problem's I've been having though.

Comment: @benjaoming and @Jasper Kennis: The else field is correct. `get_or_create` returns a two-tuple with the model instance as the first item and whether or not it was created as the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you're not actually processing the profile form. Look at the code you've written: at no point do you have anything to take the values that you've entered for the user profile and save them to the database.

Also, `admin.StackedInline` is not built for the purpose you're trying to use it for. That manages one-to-many relationships, not one-to-one relationships.

If you must have the functionality in the admin follow exactly the setup that you are outlining, probably your best shot is to add a custom view to `AdminSite` with the forms for adding and editing users. Alternatively, have people edit two forms to create a user.

Anyway, you can read more about [adding views to an `AdminSite`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).

Comment: You're right, this seems to be why an "empty" version of a UserProfile is being saved. I have to admit I thought about that but couldn't find these parameters available in the method anywhere. The request object isn't present, for example.

Overwriting the Django admin pages seems a bit too ugly to me though, I'll separate the forms again, so much for usability, the administrators of this project are smart enough to use two separate forms and I'll pass a feature request to the Django development team to auto-extend the User admin. Tnx for the help!